# Find element in Integers satisfying certain equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find $x$, such that 
$$4 \cos ^2(x)\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
I tried two methods:

```
NSolve[4 Cos[x]^2 \[Element] Integers, x]
```

and

```
NSolve[4 Cos[x]^2 == z, x, {z \[Element] Integers}]
```

I can't really think of any other way to tell Mathematica what I want, and I also don't really understand why the two above methods don't work. Could someone elaborate?

Comment: try `NSolve[{4 Cos[x]^2 == z, z \[Element] Integers}, x]`?

Comment: `Solve[FractionalPart[4 Cos[x]^2] == 0, x, Reals]`

Comment: @kglr: One of the answers of your code is {x -> ConditionalExpression[
   1. (-1. ArcCos[-0.5 Sqrt[z]] + 6.28319 C[1]), (z | C[
      1]) \[Element] Integers].

Comment: `Solve[4 Cos[x]^2 == #, x, Reals] & /@ Range[0, 4]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: How does it work? How did you com to  Range[0, 4]?

Comment: Amplitude is 4 and function is nonnegative..

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: Thank you. This is rather by hand.